# Creating 6 piles from 54 cards, what is the chance of 1 having 9 blacks and 1 having 9 reds?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, card-games

With a randomly shuffled $54$ card deck (including the $2$ jokers), I made $6$ piles of $9$ cards, placing $1$ card in each pile sequentially.

What are the chances $1$ pile is entirely black and another is entirely red?
[This happened earlier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVQSu.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: So initial thoughts was 2 binomial trials n=9 p=0.5 x=9 but obviously that doesnt really work when its deck of cards and I didn't really have the effort or knowledge to fully figure it out hence why im asking here

Comment: Second question: Are jokers considered part of colors or no?

Comment: No in this situation theyre colorless

Comment: Simulation suggests that the probability is approximately $\frac{1}{15000}$

Comment: Just did my own simulation and it got similar results of $1/15000$ - $1/16000$

Answer (score 0):

Since there are only 26 cards in a colour, you cannot have more than two hands with whole red, and likewise for black.

You seek the probability for:

- One whole red, one whole black, and four mixed hands.
- One whole red, two whole black, and three mixed hands.
- Two whole red, one whole black, and three mixed hands.
- Two whole red, two whole black, and two mixed hands.

Use the principle of inclusion and exclusion to count these hands.

Comment: While this is true not sure what how you'd get to a percentage chance from this

Comment: Just divide the count for favoured hands, by the count for total hands.